# How can I find a smoothest complex analytic function with a (finite) set of prescribed function values?

Tags: complex-analysis, soft-question, affine-geometry, inverse-problems

How can I find the smoothest complex analytic function $$x+yi \to u+vi$$ with a finite set of points having prescribed values $$\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\},\{y_1,\cdots,y_n\},\{u_1,\cdots,u_n\},\{v_1,\cdots,v_n\}$$

This question is mostly regarding algebraic or analytical methods to find a solution.

***Own work***

Being a MSc EE specialized in applied mathematics, I have with linear algebra managed to find approximants by expressing the Cauchy-Riemann equations
$$\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{dv}{dy}$$ $$\frac{du}{dy} = -\frac{dv}{dx}$$
on a discretized Cartesian grid with added smoothness regularizing term using the vector-gradient $+\epsilon_1\|\nabla v\|$ as well as a small Tikhonov regularization term $\epsilon_2\|v\|$

For example here we force $0.5 \to 2$. The image represents complex numbers in a way so that the non-black color purple corresponds to the vector (2,0).

[image]
Found solution :
[image]

By ocular inspection I suppose this solution is suspiciously close to the affine transformation that rotates around some point somewhere in the neighborhood of $(0.5,0.25)$. Perhaps this would be a suitable exercise for a curious student to prove that a first order polynomial possibly with some extra restrictions has a homomorphism (I have hardly studied abstract algebra.. am I using this word right?) to affine transformations on the plane.

Comment: Look up Lagrange interpolation for polynomials and find a degree $n-1$ polynomial sending $x_k+iy_k$ to $u_k+iv_k$

Comment: Lagrange interpolation will not ensure that Cauchy-Riemann will be fulfilled. Or will it?

Comment: if it's an analytic polynomial $P(z)=a_0+a_1z+..a_kz^k$ it will will work as you can easily see by inspection since monomials in $z$ satisfy C-R

Comment: Aha. I interpreted it as to try and separately fit real and imaginary part to their own polynomials.

Comment: That is tricky because you would need polynomials of two real variables and those are quite different than analytic polynomials